# Error mvn gcloud:run JAVA

Tags: gcloud

I've been trying hard to run & deploy my java project in google compute vm. I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-guestbook-extras but always receiving this error:

```
[INFO]     params['tls'] = docker.docker.tls.TLSConfig(
[INFO] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'docker'  
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1
```

I'm running MacOS Yosemite 10.10.3. Last versions of docker, virtual box, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so I'm adding this as an answer. I'll edit once I have a real answer for you.

What version of gcloud do you have? Can you post the output of `gcloud info`? I think this may be fixed in the latest version of gcloud.

Once you have that information, try running `gcloud components update` and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried without any success. The error has change: [INFO]   File "/Users/richard/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/docker/containers.py", line 48, in <module>
[INFO]     from docker import docker
[INFO] ImportError: cannot import name docker
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1
[ERROR] 
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: gcloud app xxx exit code is: 1

Comment: Richards-MacBook-Pro:stage1 richard$ gcloud info
Google Cloud SDK [0.9.63]

Platform: [Mac OS X, x86_64]
Python Version: [2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Comment: Do you have docker-py installed? There are a few suggested workarounds for this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=125).

Comment: Yep. That's it. I Had to read all answers but finally found solution by changing manually some lines in containers.py. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in a shell, dollar symbol included

$(boot2docker shellinit)

You may find this useful
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same error recently. You seem to be using an outdated plugin version for gcloud-maven-plugin (most probably 1.9.17 or 1.9.17a). Update the version to a version equal to or after 0.9.57 from here [Gcloud Maven PLugin versions](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/gcloud-maven-plugin/).